# How to make slider responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I found this tutorial: [How to make slider](http://rafbm.github.io/howtomakeaslider/)
I tried to changed the `.slider { width: 100%;}` and `li {width: 100%;}` intended to make it responsive but doesn't works. Any idea how to make it responsive?

Comment: Please share the minimal code required in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add `width:100%` to `.slider and .slider > ul` as well

Answer (score 0):

There is this javascript

```
this.ul.style.width = (this.li[0].clientWidth * this.li.length) + 'px'
```

since the li floated left the UL width is set to each li width * number of li items

So, in the tutorial the UL width is 1600px, when you set it to 100% and also set the li to 100% you will only be left with one li item.

What is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: I want the div slider responsive every time I stretch the browser but the problem is the picture is to big evrytime I stretch it.